# No matching function for call to moveitVisualTools::publishCollisionWall...etc

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the book "Mastering Ros for Robotics Programming" from Lenthin Joseph... in chapter 10 learning to Grasp with Movelt. I wish to launch the "grasp_generator_server.launch" from the seven_dof_arm_gazebo package...however I am having numerous errors which I could not alone solve when I builded the workspace using catkin_make. Below I am pasting the main errors:

1 - /home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/custom_environment2.h:78:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools::publishCollisionWall(double, int, int, double, const string&)’I am following the book "Mastering Ros for Robotics Programming" from Lenthin Joseph... in chapter 10 learning to Grasp with Movelt. I wish to launch the "grasp_generator_server.launch" from the seven_dof_arm_gazebo package...however I am having numerous errors which I could not alone solve when I builded the workspace using catkin_make. Below I am pasting the main errors:

1 - /home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/custom_environment2.h:78:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘mo
tools_->publishCollisionWall(-0.55, 0,     0,      2.2,   WALL1_NAME);  // back

2 -  home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps_test.cpp:99:20: error: ‘class moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools’ has no member named ‘setMuted’
visual_tools_->setMuted(false);

3 -/home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps_test.cpp:116:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools::loadEEMarker(std::**cxx11::string&, std::**cxx11::string&)’
visual_tools*->loadEEMarker(grasp_data*.ee_group*, planning_group_name*);

4- no matching function for call to ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools::publishEEMarkers(geometry_msgs::Pose&, rviz_visual_tools::colors, const char [9])’
visual_tools_->publishEEMarkers(pose, rviz_visual_tools::GREEN, "test_eef")

5 - /home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/simple_grasps_test.cpp:145:22: error: ‘class moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools’ has no member named ‘publishBlock’
visual_tools_->publishBlock(object_pose, rviz_visual_tools::BLUE, BLOCK_SIZE)

6- /home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter_test.cpp:185:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools::publishAnimatedGrasps(std::vector<moveit_msgs::Grasp_std::allocator<void > >&, std::**cxx11::string&)’
visual_tools*->publishAnimatedGrasps(possible_grasps, grasp_data*.ee_parent_link_);

7- /home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/src/grasp_filter_test.cpp:186:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools::publishIKSolutions(std::vector<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint_std::allocator<void >, std::allocator<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint_std::allocator<void > > >&, std::**cxx11::string&, double)’
visual_tools*->publishIKSolutions(ik_solutions, planning_group_name*, 0.25);

I have already looked to /opt/ros/kinetic/include/moveit_visual_tools in "moveit_visual_tools.h" and the objects AnimatedGrasps, Wall, etc are configured correct (I guess) very similar as the object Table is configured...and the object Table presented any problem....Why I am having problems with these other objects? I also looked in the cpp files in src directory which is inside the moveit_simple_grasps directory.....Someone can assist me with this issue? I lost all they long trying to solve these errors....I tried to modify the cpp codes...changing some lines as suggested davetcoleman in "Fixed API changes in moveit_visual_tools"  but unfortunately the errors kept.... I am using Ros- kinect and ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for advance.errors....I tried to modify the cpp codes...changing some lines as suggested davetcoleman in "Fixed API changes in moveit_visual_tools"  but unfortunately the errors kept.... I am using Ros- kinect and ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327211/no-matching-function-for-call-to-moveitvisualtools::publishcollisionwall...etc/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-27**:
What do you mean by

> the main errors

? Can you post the output of `catkin_make` instead of an abbreviated version?

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2019-06-27**:
The errors msg is over the allowed that is why I put the error which appeared more often and more than 1 time....( I know they should appear only once but they were displayed numerous times).Maybe the problem is that I cannot identify the error....a C++ lack of knowledge. I only would like to understand what is happening and where I need to go to change the code....is it in launch files, cpp files,..plugin .h files in the moveit_visual_tools in source (/opt/ros/kinect/include/moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h?) because I tried to change some line of codes but I could not solve. Could you please give an easy example what this problems means: "no mathing function for call to X::Y::publishZ(etc....) ....X, Y and Z is only an course example....maybe if you explain what this error means and give an example to correct an issue like this...I can later correct these numerous similar erros too. Thanks very much in advance!!! I am new in Ros and in Forum, so I am sorry for the mistakes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-28**:
Seeing as these are errors in one very specific package / from a book, I would suggest you contact the author(s) of the book. You can do that at [qboticslabs/mastering_ros/issues](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks guys I solved my problem as @gvdhoorn suggested I looked in qbotics/mastering_ros/issues...they had updated the code which was with some issues....the file is provided here in:

https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/master/chapter_10_codes/moveit_simple_grasps_1.zip

However the code also were not working well... the following error RAMAINED:

"/home/marcus/catkin_ws/src/moveit_simple_grasps/include/moveit_simple_grasps/custom_environment2.h:78:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘mo tools_->publishCollisionWall(-0.55, 0, 0, 2.2, WALL1_NAME); // back"

Well this error I corrected...giving a double argument in tha matrix position 5 (WALL_NAME)...in this place the source code in "user/opt/ros/kinetic/inculde/moveitvisualtools/moveitvisualtools.h" it is asked to enter with 7 arguments the first 5 arguments are double (pose and dimensions of the object = collisiowalll) and the last 2 are the name (wall1_name or other) and the color of the object in RVIZ (GREEN for example).... so I added a float argument in the cell it was named with a char....like this:
publishCollisionWall (-0.55,0,0,2.2,1.5,WALL1_NAME, rvt::GREEN) and it worked!

Where rvt is ...

namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools

I would like to close this question.

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) with karma: 266 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0